# Not able to display Lightning component in Sites

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, force.com-sites

Based on latet Spring 17 release notes,
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_apps_public.htm

I am trying to display lightning component in sites. I have a sample lightning component, visualforce page showing the component and a public site. Visualforce page is added to the site. When I preview the site as admin, nothing is shown on the visualforce page and it is blank.

Below is my sample

App

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:mySampleComponent"/>
</aura:application>
```

Component

```
<aura:component >
    <ui:outputText value="This is a sample lightning component" />        
</aura:component>
```

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />


    <div id="lightningComp"/>
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:mySampleApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:mySampleComponent",
          { },
          "lightningComp",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        },'SITE URL GOES HERE'

      );

    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Any insight on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to enable Salesforce communities to get it working .The docs clearly mentions that for lightning out to work for guest users you need Salesforce communities enabled .

Also any error will show up in browser console .Open console and look for errors .

Comment: I need a page that will only be accessed by guest users. There will be no login involved. Does it make sense to use communities for this ?

Comment: Yes sure .You can still use communities .The problem here is simple salesforce allows lightning out only in communities enabled org .Hope that helps you

Comment: I was able to do this using communities as suggested by Mohith. Thanks Mohith!!